# Installing ubuntu12.10 and wine1.4 on offline

Tags: 12.10, wine, winetricks

I have a computer with dual core CPU, RAM 2GB and HDD 250GB. I have been installed windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10 on offline. The space i have allocated for ubuntu12.10 is 25GB. I have no internet. I have installed ubuntu12.10-desktop-i386.iso  with the following partition structure.

```
sda5 ext4   / 11000MB   
sda6 ext4   /home 11000MB   
sda7 swap area   3000MB
```

I want to install windows application and games on ubuntu. So I tried to install wine1.4 typing the following command in the terminal and placed wine1.4 folder on desktop.
`sudo apt-get install wine1.4`

But I am getting the following error.

```
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to locate package wine1.4
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'wine1.4'
```

I don't know what to do. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

`Apt-get` needs internet to work for the regular case, this is the main why it is not working.

What do you mean "placed wine1.4 folder ondesktop" did you check out their source code? If so you would need to follow their instructions

You should be able to get the .deb file from another machine with internet and transfer it to this one, but you also need to grab all the necessary dependancies as well. You can download it from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wine1.4)